# Transition not working when transform from one position to another using JS / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Code transition not working for Title and for the textbox when moving it using Javascript.
I'm using bootstrap 5 for my HTML/css

Goal: 
1)For title, change text via `.textContent="aaa"` should transition the text instead of instantly changing
2)When moving the textarea, it will slowly transition to the new location instead of instantly changing

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 order-sm-1 p-5 fs-2" id="nayami-title">Title</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="row p-5 l-1">
            <div class="form-floating textBox" id="nayamiTextBox">
                <textarea class="form-control nayami-box" placeholder="aaa"
                id="floatingTextarea2" 
                style="height: 200px;width:70%;font-size: 60px;"
                maxlength="35"></textarea>
                <div class="formLabel">
                    <label for="floatingTextarea">Write your worry here</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
            <div class="row position-absolute bottom-0 start-100 translate-middle-x b-1 r-1">
                <div class="col" id="nayami-button">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning button-large" onclick="nayami()"><span class="fs-1">OK</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code

```
.textBox{
    margin-left:10rem;
}
#nayamiTextBox{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;   
}
#nayami-title{
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

@keyframes FadeInAndOut {
    0%{ opacity: 0 }
    50%,100%  { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Javascript

```
function nayami(){

    var nayamiCount = 0;
    var nayamiText=document.getElementById("floatingTextarea2");
    var nayamiTextBox1 = document.getElementById("nayamiTextBox");
    var nayamiTitle = document.getElementById("nayami-title");
    var nayamiImg1 = document.getElementById("nayamiImage");
    var advisor1 = document.getElementById("speechBubble");
    var advisor2 = document.getElementById("speechBubble2");
    var nayamiButton = document.getElementById("nayami-button");
    var buttonAns = document.getElementById("buttonAnswer");
    var buttonAns2 = document.getElementById("buttonAnswer2");

    if(nayamiCount==0){
        if(nayamiText.value==""){
            alert("Warning");
        }else{
            nayamiImg1.style.opacity=1;
            nayamiText.style.color="red";
            nayamiText.readOnly=true;
            nayamiCount++;
        }
    }else if(nayamiCount==1){
        nayamiTitle.classList.add('FadeInAndOut');
        nayamiTitle.textContent="Open";
        nayamiCount++;
    }else if(nayamiCount==2){
        nayamiImg1.style.top = 15+"rem";
        nayamiImg1.style.right = 25+"rem";
        nayamiImg1.style.width =15+"%";
        nayamiTextBox1.style.right = 18+"rem";
        nayamiTextBox1.style.top = 18+"rem";
        nayamiCount++;
    }
```

Comment: Where you call your nayami method ?

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui Thanks for the comment, i added it just now sorry.

Comment: I still unable to find nayamiImage element, i recommend you to upload your complete mark-up. Thank you

Comment: Do you want nayamiCount to increment every time you click ?

Comment: Hi Charles, Ive got that sorted, every time i click nayamiCount increments only problem is what ive said above